# Unable to Run GCM (C2DM) on emulator/Virtual Machine: API level 14

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

App Crashes throwing exception while launching:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf

What should be configuration of emulator and VM?

Comment: Make sure your emulator is one with the Google APIs, not just a plain Android emulator.

Comment: Also, once you're using the emulator with Google API, goto 'Settings'->Accounts & Sync and Add your Google/Gmail account to it, otherwise you won't be able to register for GCM.

Comment: @azgolfer: Received error: PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR

Comment: Are you using emulator 2.2 and above, with Google API?

Comment: Compiled in: API 16(SDK 4.1)
Emulator Configuration: Google API 8(SDK 2.2). Also added google accout.

Comment: After deploying the server in AppEngine, I was able to successfully register. Now facing problem on sending message to registered device.
On Server side following exception occurs while trying to send message.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender

Same problem as discussed here
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-c2dm/Q74hd6Ouw84

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution for this problem.

You should create a new Emulator using Google Api. then, re deploy your app in this new android emulator.

The result:

```
08-06 19:18:55.590: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(841): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
08-06 19:18:55.590: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(841): GCM IntentService class: org.gdglima.taller.labuno.GCMIntentService
08-06 19:18:55.600: V/GCMBaseIntentService(841): Acquiring wakelock
08-06 19:18:55.630: V/GCMBaseIntentService(841): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-1
08-06 19:18:55.710: D/GCMBaseIntentService(841): handleRegistration: registrationId = APA91bHoqz3F7X-QByP8pvOuyZQHthpQB6vrL_3REPOtO8GrCsD_aXrfNzvW4zxbtfkoXMAAjnf0wuARu12h9O4HP-4IHJI6peFRlDkdZC0MqzJhdw47_8VspjsiwDysmEp9_W4RdoPaIzK0bxiTIeGaEMkkK8oq-Q, error = null, unregistered = null
08-06 19:18:55.710: D/GCMRegistrar(841): resetting backoff for org.gdglima.taller.labuno
08-06 19:18:55.730: V/GCMRegistrar(841): Saving regId on app version 1
08-06 19:18:55.870: D/GCMTest(841): REGISTRATION: onRegistered OK.
08-06 19:18:55.930: V/GCMBaseIntentService(841): Releasing wakelock
```

Comment: Was able to successfully register after following commonsware and azgolfer. Can't able to send message from server. Please Check my last comment under the question.

Comment: Hi, @dmotta, I am not getting REGISTRATION: onRegistered OK, after having successfull new regId, and its saving on app version, and wakelock releasing... but no OK registered... thus I am not able to generate push notification, because on message received through GCM on my device regId,
do you have any idea, what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

If you got  "Received error: PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR " in the AVD.
you should restart your APP,then you will get the right information.